# command = window.destroy doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
b1=Button(window, text="close", command=window.destroy)
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
window.mainloop()
```

In this code, when I execute and push a button of window "close", the window never close, infinite loading, until I task kill it.

No error happens. Could you explain what happened or Is there another way to close a window?
otherwise, this is my hardware problem?

I am using:

> Macbook air 2012 model
>
> python 3.6.6
>
> jupyter lab

Thank you!

Comment: This works fine (i.e. I can click the button to close the window) on my Mac, Python 3.6.x command line (`python3 a_file_with_that_code.py`).

What do you mean with "infinite loading"?

Comment: works fine for me, can you provide a screenshot of what you are getting?